# Is it possible to coerce int literals to floats in Rust without adding decimal point?

Tags: floating-point, rust, literals

I have some test data formatted from another language. The data is an array of floats, however some members miss the decimal point.

`[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0.5], ...` (100's more items).

Is there a way to have Rust define an array of `f64` / `f32` without having to add the decimal point to every value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it must have a decimal point.

You can use float literals with just the point: `0.` or with the point and a decimal: `0.0`.

Only if you use an explicit type suffix is it allowed to omit the point: `0f32` or `0_f32` and so on are legal.

Comment: *Only if you use an explicit type suffix is it allowed to omit the point* — so, the answer to the question *Is there a way to have Rust define an array of f64 / f32 without having to add the decimal point to every value* is **yes**.

Comment: That's pedantic and not what the question is about.